# Collapsible menu using menu block

Tags: 7, blocks

Anyone knows how to render the parent items of menu and click on the parent item toggle the sub menu of particular parent menu item using menu block or any other way ??

I am using Menu block to render the block of menus and that module render the tree of whole menu with all sub levels.

I want something like this, if i render the block it should display only parent terms in blocks and on the click of the parent term it should open the sub menu of that parent item below the parent menu item.

How can i achieve this ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to ask.

Comment: i have edited the question, hope now you can understand this question

Comment: Are any of the popular modules going to work like Nice Menus or Superfish ? When you hover on a parent item it will expand the menus nested within.